# invient chart add on-vaadin indication in web.xml

Tags: charts, vaadin

I have learnt from other posts that the mainServlet file has to be modified according to the Demo code. N then servlet file had to be indicated in web.xml
However, in my web.xml, I already had a servlet class indicated in order to use my Rest service.

Question: How can I solve this?

Following is what I am doing:

## 1:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdapter</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletAdapter</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Problem is that Invient Widgetset won't be loaded.

## 2: and if I had to indicate the servletfile here, then how I am supposed to let my Rest Service works? My Rest service is used to for secure login with auth-constrain.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VaadinApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>suricate.vaadin.MyApplicationServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>application</param-name>
        <param-value>suricate.vaadin.MyApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>com.example.myapp.widgetset.MyAppWidgetSet</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

I hope someone could help me out of this. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the `writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts` method in the `ApplicationServlet` class and inject the required invient chart js and css files.

Here is what I have done.

```
public class TogetherApplicationServlet extends ApplicationServlet {

    @Override
    protected void writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(Window window,
            String themeName, Application application, BufferedWriter page,
            String appUrl, String themeUri, String appId,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {

        page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\""
                + appUrl
                + "/modules/core/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js\"></script>\n");
        page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\""
                + appUrl + "/modules/core/js/highcharts.js\"></script>\n");
        page.write("<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"javascript\" src=\""
                + appUrl
                + "/modules/core/js/modules/exporting.js\"></script>\n");

        super.writeAjaxPageHtmlVaadinScripts(window, themeName, application,
                page, appUrl, themeUri, appId, request);
    }

}
```

You will have to modify your `suricate.vaadin.MyApplicationServlet` like I have done above. Make sure to include the correct path to the invient chart js and css files.